# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] With Where IN

Tags: mysql

I'm running Panda Resort CMS locally on XAMP, PHP 8.0.3, Mariadb/Phpmyadmin 5.1.0 so the "article" module is returning a SQLSTATE error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND checked = 1 AND lang = 1 ORDER BY rank'

Exactly at line 28

```
<?php
    if($article_alias == "") err404();
    
    if($article_id > 0){
        
        $title_tag = $article['title']." - ".$title_tag;
        $page_title = $article['title'];
        $page_subtitle = $article['subtitle'];
        $page_alias = $article['alias'];
        $publish_date = $article['publish_date'];
        $edit_date = $article['edit_date'];
        
        if(is_null($publish_date)) $publish_date = $article['add_date'];
        if(is_null($edit_date)) $edit_date = $publish_date;
        
        $result_article_file = $db->query(
                "SELECT * 
                FROM pm_article_file 
                WHERE id_item = ".$article_id." 
                AND checked = 1 
                AND lang = ".DEFAULT_LANG." 
                AND type = 'image' 
                AND file != '' 
                ORDER BY rank 
                LIMIT 1");
        if($result_article_file !== false && $db->last_row_count() > 0){
            
            $row = $result_article_file->fetch();
            
            $file_id = $row['id'];
            $filename = $row['file'];
            
            if(is_file(SYSBASE."medias/article/medium/".$file_id."/".$filename))
                $page_img = getUrl(true).DOCBASE."medias/article/medium/".$file_id."/".$filename;
        }
        
        $result_tag = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pm_tag WHERE id IN (".$article['tags'].") AND checked = 1 AND lang = ".LANG_ID." ORDER BY rank");
        if($result_tag !== false){
            $nb_tags = $db->last_row_count();
            
            $article_tags = "";
            foreach($result_tag as $i => $row){
                $tag_id = $row['id'];
                $tag_value = $row['value'];
    
                $article_tags .= $tag_value;
                if($i+1 < $nb_tags) $article_tags .= ", ";
            }
        }
        
    }else err404();
    
    check_URI(DOCBASE.$page_alias);
```

I'm really stuck at this one any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is `$article['tags']` empty? It's a syntax error to use `IN()` with nothing inside.

Comment: Wow dude! You're amazing. it really was empy! Please post an answer so i mark it because this kind of errors are deceiving to beginners. The exceptions are badly handled it was supposed to return undefined variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful to check if your variables are empty before you interpolate them into an SQL query. If `$article['tags']` is empty, you could end up with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pm_tag WHERE id IN () AND checked = 1 AND lang = 123 ORDER BY rank
```

It's a syntax error to run an `IN()` expression with an empty list. There has to be at least one value inside the parentheses.

One way you can reduce this risk is to stop using string-interpolation, and start using **query parameters.** This is safer for several reasons, and it also makes it easier to write code because you don't have to get eyestrain counting your open-quote-close-quote-open-quote-close-quote-open-quote-close-quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation Mr Bill. And def yes to query parameters! the open-close-quote are the stupidest thing introduced to php.

Comment: I can imagine a paper titled "String concatenation considered harmful" (following the [pattern started in 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful))